# Check each sequence of element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to check each occurrence of `<Record>` if the value of attribute currencyID should always have the same value. If one of the attribute has different value it should output the value of '1' in new element `<Value>` else '0'. My XSLT is this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Amount">
    <Value>
       <xsl:value-of select="if (not((./@currencyID)[1] != ./@currencyID)) then '1' else '0'"/>
    </Value>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My xml file is:

```
<Data>
<Record>
    <Amount currencyID="EUR">1.00</Amount>
    <ID>111</ID>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Amount currencyID="EUR">2.00</Amount>
    <ID>222</ID>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Amount currencyID="GBP">3.00</Amount>
    <ID>333</ID>
</Record>
</Data>
```

**GENERATED OUTPUT:**

```
<Data>
<Record>
    <Value>1</Value>
    <ID>111</ID>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Value>1</Value>
    <ID>222</ID>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Value>1</Value>
    <ID>333</ID>
</Record>
</Data>
```

The generated output is correct, however, if I change the value of currencyID in the 3rd occurrence to 'EUR', the value generated should be '0'. But, currently I get the same output. Is there something wrong in my condition?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, the output `Value` elements would either be all `0` (if all the currencies were the same), or all `1` (if at least one currency was different?). Thanks!

Comment: @TimC: yes, you're correct. '0' will generate if all the currencies are the same, if not or at least one of the currency is different it will be '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, is use a global variable to check if all the currencies are the same or not, and then just use that output the value.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="curr" select="if (/Data/Record[1]/Amount/@currencyID != /Data/Record/Amount/@currencyID) then '1' else '0'" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Amount">
    <Value>
       <xsl:value-of select="$curr"/>
    </Value>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```